# $f$ be a continuous and non-negative, that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f(x)=0$. If the series is convergent, then the integral is convergent.

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Prove or disprove:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and non-negative function such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f(x)=0$.

1. If the series $\sum_{n=k}^\infty f(n)$ is convergent, then the integral $\int_{k}^\infty f(x)dx$ is convergent.
2. If the integral $\int_{k}^\infty f(x)dx$ is convergent, then the series  $\sum_{n=k}^\infty f(n)$ is convergent.

I'm sure I need to disprove them, But I can't figure out the answer.

My thoughts:

I am trying to find out a function that is not monotonically decreasing. I am pretty sure I won't find a monotonically increasing function, because it won't converge, so I need a trigonometric function. 
I need the trigonometric function to be in a absolute value, so it won't be negative. But it seems like it works all the time.

I'd like if someone can continue my train of thought, or tell me I'm wrong. Hints will be much appreciated.

EDIT: I think I can use a function that has the value $1/n^2$ for natural numbers, but for unnatural numbers has the value of n. But then again i need it to be continuous...

Comment: For the first one, consider $\left|\frac{\sin \pi x}{x}\right|$

Comment: That sounds good. Is $|sin(x\pi)|$ good too?

Comment: Here's an idea for the second one. Suppose $f(n) = \frac 1n$ for all $n \geq k$. Then, for each point $(n, \frac 1n)$ construct a thin triangle with vertices $(n - 2^{-n}, 0)$ and $(n + 2^{-n}, 0)$. Interpolate linearly so that $f$ is defined for all $x \geq k$. It's easy to see the integral converge, but $\sum f(n)$ doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x) := \max\{x(1-x), 0\}$, and define
$$
f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} h(x-n),
\qquad x\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
It is plain that $f(n) = 0$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$
and $\lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x) = 0$.
On the other hand, $\int_0^{+\infty} f(x)\, dx = +\infty$.